# How long should it take to restore about 100 user apps with Titanium backup?

Tags: titanium-backup

I recently upgraged my Galaxy S I9000 to ICS (AOKP).  Before that I backed up all of my data using TB and restored it after the upgrade.

I recently upgraded to TB Pro, and was looking forward to the fast restores. To my surprise, TB took about 3 hours to restore ~100 apps. Is this normal?  How long should I expect it to take?

Comment: This seems like it would be pretty hard to gauge. 3 hours does seem kind of excessive, but then if you had 100 apps that each had 100 MB of data (for whatever reason) that would effectively be a 10 GB data transfer, which would certainly take a while. SD card speed would also be a defining factor, I imagine, since that's where the backups are typically stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes around an hour for me with 150-200 apps, with the Voodoo lagfix and a class 4 SD card.  This is under Froyo (which I wouldn't expect to matter).  I'd guess that your apps/data must just be large, as eldarerathis says.